# How to stop the browser loading process after 20 minutes?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2

I want to stop the browser loading process after 20 minutes in selenium webdriver script.

Please suggest, how to do this?

Comment: I am assuming that when you say 'Page' content you mean the ajax elements on a web page and when you say 'Browser' content you mean the rest of the elements, am I correct?

Comment: 'Page' refers to some web page like 'index.php' and browser refers to web browser like 'Firefox'.
And I need help when 'index.php' is loaded (browser screen is blank with whitespace) and browser's loading process is still in progress.

Comment: Not obvious what you want to accomplish. "some page loading problem while executing my script" is SO vague I was tempted to downvote. Do you want to execute some code during page load? Does your code fails because some elements are not present/visible? What is the error message? What is expected behavior? Consider reading up on WebDriverWait and ExpectedCondition. Many good answers for page load problems on Stack Overflow. Also, there is no THE UNIVERSAL METHOD - for modern web some pages, Javascript will NEVER stop updating SOME parts of the page.

Comment: change the question to exact requirement

Comment: You have a web server configured with more than 20 minutes for timeout?  That's awfully generous.  Why would you need something like that?

Comment: By default the Selenium Timeout is much shorter than 20 minutes, didn't the timeout stop your browser before or are you looking for something different?

Comment: Thanks for appreciative help!!
Actually that problem was because of ci tool.
I have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How to do it? Set some form of timer with an expiration of 20 minutes (either a selenium wait for one of the objects on the page if you want to be able to continue if it does load, or a thread.sleep if you literally want to sleep exactly 20 minutes and then quit). At the expiration of the timer, if it was a selenium wait, put your driver.close in the cleanup method; if it was a thread.sleep, call driver.close directly after.

But why? If your page isn't loading or is hanging, 20 minutes is a ridiculously long timeout. Will your customers wait 20 minutes on the page? Or will they give up after 30 seconds or so? And furthermore, why is your page hanging for over 20 minutes in the first place? What test case requires staring at a blank screen for 20 minutes then closing the browser? Are you sure it's an appropriate test case in the first place? If the test is "The page loads successfully", I suggest that 20 minutes is far, far too long.

Comment: Thanks for appreciative help!!
Actually that problem was because of ci tool.
I have resolved the problem.